# Get pixel-count in FoV inside VR-Sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, uv-mapping, htc-vive

Recently i made a application for HTC Vive users to view 360 degree videos. To have a point of reference, lets assume that this video had a resolution of FullHD (1920x1080). See the picture of a 3D model below for illustration:
[image: FoV 3D Model]
The field of view of a HTC Vive is 110° vertically and 100° horizontally. 
It would be okay to simplify it to a round FoV of 100°.

My question would be: How can i determine the amount of video-information inside my FoV?

Here is what i know so far:
You can create a sphere on paper and calculate its surface area by using the formulas for spherical caps. -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap
Also there seems to be a function for the UV-Mapping that is done by Unity (because this is done in Unity). That formula can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping
[image: View from the HTC Vive]

Any suggestions are welcomed!